# Linux: Intel WIFI Card stops working after hibernate

Tags: linux, fedora, network-adapter, hibernate

I have a Laptop with a Intel WIFI card (`Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a)`) and Fedora 38 installed (kernel: `6.2.15-300.fc38.x86_64`).

Since some months I face the problem that sometimes after waking up from hibernate the WIFI is unavailable.
The card is is still detected but rfkill shows it as hard-blocked.

What I tried so far:

- enabling and disabling flight-mode
- enable power for WIFI in S3 and S4 power-states in the UEFI
- reload the intel wifi kernel modules (iwlmvm, iwlwifi)

But nothing helped so far.
So I would appreciate every hint to a possible solution.

Comment: Hibernation works with BIOS.  See if you can get a newer Wireless Driver.  Consider a possible BIOS update.  Consider not using Hibernation.

Comment: @John drivers are the ones in the kerne-tree, firmware is automatically updated via package-manager, BIOS was updated.
So currently my only option is to reboot every time (which is sad, because hibernation is a very useful feature).